# Disable Windows Mobile from using Data Connection through USB or Bluetooth

Tags: windows, mobile, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5

Everytime I connect my Motorola MC 65 running Windows Mobile 6.5 to my computer using USB or Bluetooth, it begins to use the data connection through the computer rather than maintaining the connection through the on-board WiFi radio or Cell radio.

I would like the handheld to maintain it's current connection via WiFi or Cell rather than use a data connection through USB or Bluetooth. Is there anyway to prevent it from automatically setting up this network connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are talking about an Internet connection in contrast to a Work connection, you can setup your PC in USB/ActiveSync/WindowsMobileDeviceCenter to use USB only for Work connections. You have to enable "Allow data connections on device when connected to PC".
[image]

Comment: After playing around with it for hours, I am still unable to get it to work. I can browse the web and everything just fine, but the minute I insert it into the cradle, I can no longer browse. Is there any documentation on setting up connections how you described? I would like to verify I am doing it correctly.

Comment: The setting you have to change on the PC is "Allow data connect..." IS CHECKED and then toggle "This computer is connected to:" between Work and Automatic.Ensure the connection settings on the device are set "My network card connects to" for "Internet"